# Dice Animation with Swipe gestures for next face

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I'm trying to achieve a dice functionality where the user swipes a cube in a given direction and the cube does a transition or animates in the same direction & reveals the next number/character in the direction. I tried object animator but I'm not able to get the desired effect as a dice transition. Any suggestion on how to achieve it

here is the flip function im using :-

```
private void flipIt(final View viewToFlip) {

    if(endFlipValue<360){
        startFlipValue = endFlipValue;
        endFlipValue = startFlipValue + 180f;
    } else {
        startFlipValue = 0f;
        endFlipValue = 180f;
    }
    Log.d("FLIPVALUE","STARTFLIPVALUE :- "+ startFlipValue);
    Log.d("FLIPVALUE","ENDFLIPVALUE :- "+ endFlipValue);
    ObjectAnimator flip = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToFlip, "rotationY", startFlipValue, endFlipValue);
    flip.setDuration(3000);
    flip.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            buttonFlip.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            buttonFlip.setText(startFlipValue + " : " + endFlipValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
    flip.start();

}
```

The downside of this is it doesn't give a proper effect and the text is also flipped.

Comment: can you pls share the code?

Comment: @SanjayBhalani it's a simple Object Animator

Comment: try to use 6 diff image instance of an object animation

Comment: that wouldn't work as images will flip too. Plus I need it to be with alphabets